# showing and hiding the span tag on the form based on the drop down list value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following drop down list on my page. I also have a onchange event if someone selects an item from the drop down list. I can see the item index in the onchange event:

```
  @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                .Name("Awards")
                .Label(label => label.Content("Please select Award type from the list. "))
                .DataTextField("AwardCategory1")
                .DataValueField("AwardId")
                .OptionLabel("Select award")
                
                .DataSource(source =>
                {
                    source.Read(read =>
                    {
                        read.Action("GetAwards", "Home");
                    });
                })
              .Events(e => e.Change("onChange"))
            )
```

This is my onChange event:

```
<script>
  function onChange(e) {
         var dropdownlist = $("#Awards").data("kendoDropDownList");
         var text = dropdownlist.text();
         $(".award").text(text);
         alert(text);
        
    }

</script>
```

In the alert, I can see the selected item from the dropdown. I want to display some text on my web page based on the selected item so if text =="Award1" then I want to display

```
  if (text =="Award1" )
    <h3>"This is the award text for several people. Everyone will be given Award "A"></h3>
    else if (text =="Award2")
    <h3>Test this award. Please make sure, you will be on time</h3>
    else if (text =="Award3")
      .
      .
```

and so on.

How can I show the `"<h3>"` tag text on my web page based on the drop down list value. I can successfully capture the drop down list text value in JavaScript, but how can I display a certain text based on the selected item. I tried to put  this line in my Javascript function:

```
$(".award").text(text);
```

so that I can capture this in   tag like this:

```
<span class="award"></span>
```

with the above line, I can see the selected award, but I cannot display different text on my web page when a different item is selected. I dont need help with Telerik dropdown, I need help with javascript part.

any help is appreciated.

I tried the solution given below:

```
function onChange() {
        var dropdownlist = $("#Awards").data("kendoDropDownList");
        var text = dropdownlist.text();
        //$(".award").text(text);
        const award = {
            "Award1": `<h3>This is the award text for several people. Everyone will be given Award "A"></h3>`,
            "Award2": `<h3>Test this award. Please make sure, you will be on time</h3>`,
            "Award3": `<h3>Blablabla</h3>`,
        }[text]
        $(".test").text(award);
        //return { awardText: text };
    }
```

I have this on the top of my page:

```
<div id="test">

</div>
```

Comment: $(".award").text receives an htmlString, so you can add your h3 tag like this:

const html = \`<h3>This is the ... </h3>\`; $(".award").text(html);

Comment: can you give an example. I just need to hide one text and display another text if the drop down box item changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option, like you lay out yourself, is to change the innerHTML of a div when you select something.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="output"></div>
  <form name="form01">
    <select name="award">
      <option value="">Select an award</option>
      <option value="a1">Award 1</option>
      <option value="a2">Award 2</option>
      <option value="a3">Award 3</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <script>
    const output = document.getElementById('output');
    const awardtext = {
      "a1": `<h3>This is the award text for several people. Everyone will be given Award "A"</h3>`,
      "a2": `<h3>Test this award. Please make sure, you will be on time</h3>`,
      "a3": `<h3>Blablabla</h3>`
    };

    document.forms.form01.award.addEventListener('change', e => {
      if (e.target.value) {
        output.innerHTML = awardtext[e.target.value];
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Another option is to have all the texts already in the document and then hide and show them. In this example I use the [subsequent-sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators#subsequent-sibling_combinator) to style the h3 so that is shows. This is a bit tricky to use because the selectors on each side of the `~` need to be on the same level in the DOM tree.

```css
.output h3 {
  display: none;
}

form[data-award="a1"]~div.output>h3#a1 {
  display: block;
}

form[data-award="a2"]~div.output>h3#a2 {
  display: block;
}

form[data-award="a3"]~div.output>h3#a3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form name="form01">
    <select name="award">
      <option value="">Select an award</option>
      <option value="a1">Award 1</option>
      <option value="a2">Award 2</option>
      <option value="a3">Award 3</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <div class="output">
    <h3 id="a1">This is the award text for several people. Everyone will be given Award "A"</h3>
    <h3 id="a2">Test this award. Please make sure, you will be on time</h3>
    <h3 id="a3">Blablabla</h3>
  </div>
  <script>
    document.forms.form01.award.addEventListener('change', e => {
      e.target.form.dataset.award = e.target.value;
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
<script>
  function onChange(e) {
    const dropdownlist = $("#Awards").data("kendoDropDownList");
    const text = dropdownlist.text();
    const award = {
      "Award1": `<h3>This is the award text for several people. Everyone will be given Award "A"></h3>`,
      "Award2": `<h3>Test this award. Please make sure, you will be on time</h3>`,
      "Award3": `<h3>Blablabla</h3>`,
    }[text]
    $(".award").text(award);
    alert(text);

  }
</script>
```

Comment: Make sure Award1, Award2, Award3 be equal to your dropdownlist.text

Comment: how can I put a style tag in <h3> like <h3 style="font-sze:12px">

Comment: You can add inline, just like you did, or add a class="myStyle" and import a style with the .css in the html head

Comment: where can I put the actual H3 tag. I want it at the top of the page. Should I do <h3></h3> with some id

Comment: You can create a div, with some id, and replace the $(".award") with $("#someid")

Comment: I tried your solution. I made the edit to my question. can you please see what am I doing wrong because I dont see anything on my web page

Comment: I just put a <div> tag like this on top of my page <div id="test"></div>